# What are the meanings of the min and max properties in the sql configuration pool?

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js, pg

I have the configuration pool.What is confiigured here with min and max properties?

```
require('dotenv').config();
const config = {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      host:     process.env.POSTGRES_HOST || 'localhost',
      database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB || 'vo2',
      user:     process.env.POSTGRES_USER || 'postgres',
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD || 'windofchange'
    },
    pool: { min: 0, max: 10 },
    migrations: { directory: './db/migrations' }
};
module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

min - minimum no.of connections whereas max - maximum no. of connections from your application to the Postgres DB. Read about [connection pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/connection-pooling/info) and about [pool sizing](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing) and it has nothing to do with PostgreSQL as it is being handled by your application.